# Formula for SSRS - iif today display column in textbox

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, calendar

Can anyone help me out? We're on-call for 1 week at a time.
I'm trying to display on the dashboard who is on-call this week.

I'm trying to write the following formula:

Display whatever is in 'Who's on Call' column if they are on-call this week.

Please help, I just cannot put my head around it.

```
    <RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ListName>On Call Calendar</ListName>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="Title" />
    <FieldRef Name="Location" />
    <FieldRef Name="EventDate" />
    <FieldRef Name="EndDate" />
    <FieldRef Name="Description" />
    <FieldRef Name="fAllDayEvent" />
    <FieldRef Name="fRecurrence" />
    <FieldRef Name="ParticipantsPicker" />
    <FieldRef Name="Category" />
    <FieldRef Name="Facilities" />
    <FieldRef Name="FreeBusy" />
    <FieldRef Name="Overbook" />
    <FieldRef Name="Workspace0" />
    <FieldRef Name="Partial_x0020_Hours" />
    <FieldRef Name="Encoded_x0020_Absolute_x0020_URL" />
    <FieldRef Name="Item_x0020_Type" />
    <FieldRef Name="Path" />
    <FieldRef Name="URL_x0020_Path" />
    <FieldRef Name="Workflow_x0020_Instance_x0020_ID" />
    <FieldRef Name="File_x0020_Type0" />
    <FieldRef Name="_OldID" />
    <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" />
    <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle" />
    <FieldRef Name="Whos_on_Call" />
    <FieldRef Name="ID" />
    <FieldRef Name="ContentType" />
    <FieldRef Name="Modified" />
    <FieldRef Name="Created" />
    <FieldRef Name="Author" />
    <FieldRef Name="Editor" />
    <FieldRef Name="_UIVersionString" />
    <FieldRef Name="Attachments" />
    <FieldRef Name="Edit" />
    <FieldRef Name="DocIcon" />
    <FieldRef Name="ItemChildCount" />
    <FieldRef Name="FolderChildCount" />
    <FieldRef Name="AppAuthor" />
    <FieldRef Name="AppEditor" />
  </ViewFields>
</RSSharePointList>'
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using sqlserver for your dataset? Does your data have a time band for each employee when they are on call? show your full dataset with sample data please

Comment: It's SP Calendar dataset.

Comment: How do you know when someone is on call? They have to have some sort of date associated with their record right? You simply have to say if that date is between start and end time then they are on call .. or display their name like you want to

Comment: Yes, I have 'Start Time' and 'End Time' field associated/bound to 'Who's on Call' column. See screenshot above. As you can see, there is start time, end time and the right most column, 'Who's on Call'

Comment: I was working on something like this: '=IIF(Fields!Start_Time.Value = Today, "" Fields!Whos_on_Call.Value "My_Data_Set")' but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you are doing a lookup from another dataset, you need to use an aggregate (like MAX) and put your IIF inside. **=MAX(IIF(Fields!Start_Time.Value <> Today, NOTHING, Fields!Whos_on_Call.Value), "My_Data_Set")**